# why can't I download artifacts from JFrog repository?

Tags: maven, jira, artifactory

JFrog artifactory loaded 902 artifacts, I set up to upload through the repository. But I cannot download or view my artifacts. I do not quite understand even what the problem is.

[image]

[image]

Setting **maven** from a file **settings.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
   .......
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <name>libs-snapshot</name>
      <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
      <id>libs-snapshot</id>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
       ........
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

I see that the repository does not download  and tries to take data from the .m2 folder :3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this answer helped me. The problem was in the .m2 folder.Her should be deleted if you change the settings.xml in \atlassian-plugin-sdk-6.3.6\apache-maven-3.2.1\conf folder.

[image]

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775845/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bc%d1%83-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%91%d1%82-%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%b8-jira-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0/779154#779154

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you have duplication of the server-id 'maven-external' in your settings.xml.
Check your configurations.

Answer (score 0):

The actual error seems to be:

```
Goal requires a project to execute, 
but there is no POM in this directory (D:\Newfolder1)
```

So the first step would be to make sure there is a `pom.xml` before executing atlas-create-

Comment: pom.xml create atlassian. than atlassian create pom.xml necessary download artifacts in repository :3

Comment: @timob256 Sure, but make sure that pom.xml is actually created in D:\NewFolder1